# MIDI.NET receive information VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, midi

I am using a sgm studio 12 light mixing table and I bought a MIDI to USB cable to get the signals to my computer. I tried using the `MIDI.NET` to get the signals but I can't seem to find any code on how to do this except for C#

The code is

```
void PrintCC(ControlChangeMessage msg) {
Console.WriteLine("Device: " + msg.Device.Name);
Console.WriteLine("Channel: " + msg.Channel.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Control: " + msg.Control.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Value: " + msg.Value);
}
...
InputDevice inputDevice = InputDevice.InstalledDevices[0];
inputDevice.Open();
inputDevice.ControlChange += new InputDevice.ControlChangeHandler(PrintCC);
inputDevice.StartReceiving(null); 
Console.ReadKey();
```

Now, does anyone know how to do this in Visual Basic?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the same MIDI.NET library with VB.NET - VB.NET and C# are (mostly) feature-compatible, but have different syntaxes.  Include a reference to Midi.dll in your VB.NET project, and change the syntax examples to use VB.NET syntax instead of C#.   After looking on the MIDI.NET site it appears other users are doing exactly that.

This [converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) might help - but it isn't foolproof.  To start, I would convert this [example project](https://code.google.com/p/midi-dot-net/source/browse/trunk#trunk/ConsoleDemo).  I would, using Visual Studio, create a new VB.NET project and add empty .vb files with the same name as each of the .cs files that are in the example project.  Then I would wash the C# for each file through the converter, and paste the result in the files.  The curve here is pretty steep though.

Or learn C#.  C# and VB.NET really are all about the same underlying concepts.  They just look different.

Comment: Oke thanks, I this this. And I only got 2 error for 1 line but I down know how to solve it. This is the line: `inputDevice__1.ControlChange += New InputDevice.ControlChangeHandler(PrintCC)` and the errors are telling me I have to use a RaiseEvent and that InputDevice.ControlChangeHandler() requires an AdressOff. Any help?

Comment: That line is trying to assign a delegate (a function that can be called) to the ControlChange event.  The converter got confused here... change `new InputDevice.ControlChangeHandler(PrintCC)` to `AddressOf PrintCC`

Comment: I'm still having problems with it, I tried everything I could but I'm not an experienced vb programmer.. Anyone who would like to try doing this in VB.NET?

Comment: I would recommend reading Charles Petzold's book 'Programming in the Key of C#' - its short, goes through everything you'd need to know for C#, and even has a MIDI programming example at the end.  It will take you from inexperienced programmer to programmer who can work with MIDI in probably the shortest amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very striped down example of how I use MIDI-dot-NET in VB.NET. You'll need to add a reference to either the MIDI-dot-NET project (if you're using the source), or the DLL in your project.

```
''Modify the Item index as necessary:
Dim inputDevice as Midi.InputDevice = Midi.InputDevice.InstalledDevices.Item(0)
Dim outputDevice as Midi.InputDevice = Midi.OutputDevice.InstalledDevices.Item(0)

Sub ConnectDevices()
  Try
      With inputDevice
          .Open()
          .StartReceiving(Nothing)
          AddHandler .NoteOn, AddressOf NoteOn
          AddHandler .NoteOff, AddressOf NoteOff
          AddHandler .ControlChange, AddressOf ControlChange
      End With
  Catch ex As Exception
      ''Hitting this block is likely because something is already connected
      '' to the device at the Item index, try again as necessary
  End Try

  Try
      outputDevice.Open()
  Catch ex As Exception
      ''Again, probably already opened
  End Try
End Sub

Sub DisconnectDevices()
  If inputDevice.IsReceiving Then inputDevice.StopReceiving()
  If inputDevice.IsOpen Then
      inDev.Close()
      RemoveHandler inputDevice.NoteOn, AddressOf NoteOn
      RemoveHandler inputDevice.NoteOff, AddressOf NoteOff
      RemoveHandler inputDevice.ControlChange, AddressOf ControlChange
      ''Or you could do something like this:
      inputDevice.RemoveAllEventHandlers()
  End If

  If outputDevice.IsOpen Then outputDevice.Close()
End Sub

Sub NoteOn(ByVal msg As Midi.NoteOnMessage)
  ''Received a NoteOn (9X)
  Dim channel As Byte = CByte(msg.Channel)
  Dim pitch As Byte = CByte(msg.Pitch)
  Dim velocity As Byte = CByte(msg.Velocity)
End Sub
Sub NoteOff(ByVal msg As Midi.NoteOffMessage)
  ''Received a NoteOff (8X)
  Dim channel As Byte = CByte(msg.Channel)
  Dim pitch As Byte = CByte(msg.Pitch)
  Dim velocity As Byte = CByte(msg.Velocity)
End Sub
Sub ControlChange(ByVal msg as Midi.ControlChangeMessage)
  ''Received a Control Change (BX)
  Dim channel As Byte = CByte(msg.Channel)
  Dim control As Byte = CByte(msg.Control)
  Dim value As Byte = CByte(msg.Value)
End Sub
```

Adjust the three event subs to handle all of your incoming MIDI messages. Sending MIDI is a pretty simple matter, too, you just have to convert any Byte or Integer values you have to the library's type (though, I'm not sure why it uses Integers instead of Bytes).

```
Dim channel As Midi.Channel = CType(0, Midi.Channel)
Dim pitch As Midi.Pitch = CType(1, Midi.Pitch)
Dim velocity As Integer = 127
Dim control As Midi.Control = CType(1, Midi.Control)
Dim value As Integer = 127

outputDevice.SendNoteOn(channel, pitch, velocity)
outputDevice.SendNoteOff(channel, pitch, velocity)
outputDevice.SendControlChange(channel, control, value)
```

**Update:** Here's a direct conversion of the code in your question:

```
Private Sub PrintCC(ByVal msg As ControlChangeMessage)
    Console.WriteLine("Device: " & msg.Device.Name)
    Console.WriteLine("Channel: " & msg.Channel.ToString())
    Console.WriteLine("Control: " & msg.Control.ToString())
    Console.WriteLine("Value: " & msg.Value.ToString())
End Sub

Dim inputDevice As InputDevice = InputDevice.InstalledDevices(0)
inputDevice.Open()
AddHandler inputDevice.ControlChange, AddressOf PrintCC
inputDevice.StartReceiving(Nothing)
'Console.ReadKey() ''This isn't related to MIDI.Net
```

The last `Console.ReadKey()` line doesn't affect MIDI.Net; I'm assuming it's part of an example console app. If you're directly translating one of the examples you might need it, but if you're building a WinForms app, you probably don't. Remember to implement a proper `RemoveHandler inputDevice.ControlChange, AddressOf PrintCC` somewhere in your closing/disposal code, too.